# Undefined background-image on inputs in Firefox

Tags: css, html, firefox, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Using the thymeleaf starter for Spring Boot, I have a simple login form defined:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/login}" method="post">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="username" name="username" th:placeholder="#{login.form.username}"/>
    <input class="form-control" type="password" id="password" name="password" th:placeholder="#{login.form.password}"/>

    <button class="btn btn-default btn-block" type="submit" name="submit" th:text="#{login.form.submit}">Login</button>
</form>
```

When I retrieve the page in Chrome, I see the following rendered HTML:

```
<form action="/login" method="post">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username">
    <input class="form-control" type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">

    <button class="btn btn-default btn-block" type="submit" name="submit">Login</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="1bc1dbff-d675-409b-8905-05e43a907c79">
</form>
```

In Firefox, however, I see a style attribute added to the inputs, which is causing issues:

```
<form action="/login" method="post">
    <input class="form-control" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username" style="background-image: url("undefined"); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-attachment: scroll; background-size: 16px 18px; background-position: 98% 50%; cursor: pointer;" type="text">
    <input class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" style="background-image: url("undefined"); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-attachment: scroll; background-size: 16px 18px; background-position: 98% 50%; cursor: auto;" type="password">

    <button class="btn btn-default btn-block" type="submit" name="submit">Login</button>
    <input name="_csrf" value="525584fa-939b-4f48-aabf-d4dcde234599" type="hidden">
</form>
```

Why is this happening? Am I able to disable the style attribute from being added? The only workaround I have so far is to set:

```
input[type=text], input[type=password] {
/* Firefox fix */
background-image: none !important;
}
```

but that doesn't feel very elegant.

Comment: the style attribute isn't actually being added to the compiled HTML code; I'm guessing you're looking at computed styles based on inheritance or something like that.  You have to figure out where those styles are coming from originally, rather than creating hacks around it.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but if I inspect the component in Firefox and view the CSS, I see all of the background `style` definitions under `element.style`. Forgive my ignorance, but I'm not sure where exactly the problem lay